# Why using the `share` operator on the observable in `withLatestFrom` will result in an event being skipped in one of the subscriptions?

Tags: ios, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

With the code below:

```
let stringSubject = BehaviorSubject<String?>(value: nil).share()
let intSubject = BehaviorSubject<Int?>(value: nil)

let intObservable = intSubject.compactMap { $0 }

let resultingSequence = intObservable
    .take(1)
    .withLatestFrom(stringSubject) { ($0, $1) }
    .filter { $0.1 == nil }
    .map { $0.0 }

let subscriptionB = resultingSequence
    .skip(1)
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("Subscription B: \($0)") })

let subscriptionA = resultingSequence
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("Subscription A: \($0)") })

intSubject.onNext(1)

print("Finished")
```

What I was expecting is the event `1` will be handled by `subscriptionA`, i.e. printing something like:

```
Subscription A: 1
Finished
```

But in the actual result nothing was printed, i.e.

```
Finished
```

However, if the `share()` for `stringSubject` is being removed, or `share()` is added to the end of `resultingSequence`'s declaration, the expected result will be printed.

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `resultingSequence` is not shared, there are two subscriptions to `stringSubject`.  `.share()` has a parameter `replay` defining how many previously emitted sequence elements will be replayed to future subscribers, the default value of this is 0.

So when you do `stringSubject.share()` the first subscription will receive the initial value (nil) but any subsequent subscriptions will receive no values as `stringSubject` has now emitted its initial value and you've told it to replay 0 previously emitted elements to new subscribers.

Changing `.share()` to `.share(replay: 1)` also gives your desired output as the already emitted initial value will be replayed to any new subscribers.